# Possible to use different datasource for jobrepository than item reader in spring-boot-batch project?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

Just setup my first spring-boot-batch project using spring-data-jpa. I have a working solution in my dev environment, whereby I consume some rows from an Oracle DB in my itemReader, parse some xml/html out in my processor for each row, then write out each extracted html out to an individual file using a custom itemWriter. (1 file per row)

My datasource is configured via spring-data-jpa in the boot project (application.properties)...

I noticed OOTB spring-batch creates various schema objects for its jobRepository using the available datasource.

This is fine in a dev environment, but i only have "read" access in our production Oracle DB environment where my itemReader will be gettings its official data.

I tried configuring 2 datasources as outlined in the spring docs i came across.. but couldn't get it working. I also tried using in-memory instead, but couldn't get that working either.

So is this possible? Or should I keep plugging away at getting the in-memory job repo working?

I'm not too concerned with restartability at this point.. batch job will be run on my desktop as a standalone spring-boot application.

Any help, tips, information is greatly appreciated.

Update:

Trying the in-memory configuration, here is part of my batch config class:

```
   @Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {


    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfiguration.class);


    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return simpleJobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(transactionManager);
        mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        return mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }
```

Project compiles ok, but when i run, i get the following:

Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? order by JOB_INSTANCE_ID desc]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

So seems its still trying to hook up to Oracle, and not use the in-memory DB..

Answer (score 1):

well... seems this config has done the trick for my case.

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {


    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchConfiguration.class);


    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Bean
    public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        simpleJobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return simpleJobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactory(ResourcelessTransactionManager txManager)
            throws Exception {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(txManager);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory) throws Exception {
         return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager  resourcelessTransactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobExplorer jobExplorer(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory) {
        return new SimpleJobExplorer(factory.getJobInstanceDao(), factory.getJobExecutionDao(),
                factory.getStepExecutionDao(), factory.getExecutionContextDao());
    }
```

Comment: In my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553985/i-would-like-to-create-a-spring-batch-project-where-batch-does-not-use-my-dataso I explained how to use different datasources. Please not that using the MapJobRepository for production ist NOT recommended by SpringBatch.