# To use the default BatchConfigurer the context must contain no more thanone DataSource, found 2

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, db2, spring-batch

I am using spring boot and spring batch. For meta table i want to use mysql and for all business thing i want to use db2 as a database.When i implemented getting error.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/local
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.seconddatasource.url=jdbc:db2://***************
spring.seconddatasource.username=******
spring.seconddatasource.password=****
spring.seconddatasource.driverClassName=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

**BatchCongig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSourceSecond;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.seconddatasource")
    public javax.sql.DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public javax.sql.DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<User> reader()
    {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<User> reader=new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(dataSourceSecond);
        reader.setSql("Select ACCT_ID from ACCT_table FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY");
        reader.setRowMapper(new UserRowerMapper());
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserItemProcessor processor()
    {
        return new UserItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1()
    {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<User,User>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job1()
    {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobakjkkj")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();

    }

}
```

**error stack**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:779) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at com.schwab.cat.SpringBatchDbReadApplication.main(SpringBatchDbReadApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: To use the default BatchConfigurer the context must contain no more thanone DataSource, found 2
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration.getConfigurer(AbstractBatchConfiguration.java:108) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration.initialize(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:114) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$ReferenceTargetSource.createObject(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:142) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.AbstractLazyCreationTargetSource.getTarget(AbstractLazyCreationTargetSource.java:86) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.getJobInstances(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.getNextJobParameters(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:131) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:212) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:231) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:123) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:117) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:776) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

I found one jira https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2537 which say that "@Primary datasource with @EnableBatchProcessing does not work for using multiple datasources" if this is correct please tell me how i can achive same.
I also found this [How to use 2 or more databases with spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362546/how-to-use-2-or-more-databases-with-spring) but not helpful in my case.

Comment: First of all I suggest creating 2 configuration 1 for the batch infrastructure and another that only contains your job configuration (Step etc). You batch configuration should configure the batch infra itself instead of relying on the default batch configured. To do this implement `BatchConfigurer` yourself and disable batch auto configuration (you could try by removing the `@EnableBatchProcessing` and see how Spring Boot handles the autoconfig (instead of plain Spring Batch).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @M.Deinum , sorry but i'm new to spring boot and batch . If you will be more descriptive , that will help me or if can provide one example thanks in advance :)

Comment: The shortest, remove `@EnableBatchProcessing` and see what happens. If that doesn't work, do as described, split configuration in 2 and let the infrastructure configuration implement `BatchConfigurer`.

Answer (score 0):

As M. Deinum suggested, I would also put the configuration of the datasources in a separate file.

Beside that, there are the following problems in your configuration file:

1. SpringBatch looks for a datasource named "dataSource" (note the capital S). If it doesn't find one, it looks for any datasource it finds. However, if it finds more than one, it throws an exception -> the one you observed.
2. In your configuration file, you create two datasources and inject one (@Autowired Datasource dataSourceSecond). This would cause the next problem, since you don't have a datasource with this name. (You only defined the datasources "secondaryDataSource" and "primaryDataSource"). This would also lead to an exception.

Here is how I would organise my configurations

```
@Configuration
public DatasourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.seconddatasource")
    public javax.sql.DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    // note the new name: dataSource -> this is the name springBatch is looking for
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public javax.sql.DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import(DatasourceConfiguration.class)
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    // note the name
    @Autowired
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource;


    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<User> reader()
    {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<User> reader=new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();

        // note the name
        reader.setDataSource(secondaryDataSource);
        reader.setSql("Select ACCT_ID from ACCT_table FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY");
        reader.setRowMapper(new UserRowerMapper());
        return reader;
    }

   ...
```

I've also written an more thouroughly answer to a similar question:
[I would like to create a spring batch project where batch does not use my datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553985/i-would-like-to-create-a-spring-batch-project-where-batch-does-not-use-my-dataso/40583783#40583783)