# Integrate kie-server into spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, jbpm, kie-server

I want to integrate all the kie-server autoconfiguration (especially JBPM) in my spring boot application.
I added these gradle dependencies in a separate module of my project

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.kie', name: 'kie-server-spring-boot-starter', version: '7.29.0.Final'
    compile group: 'xerces', name: 'xercesImpl', version: '2.12.0'
}
```

then I added the configuration properties suggested by this link

https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/master/kie-spring-boot/kie-spring-boot-samples/jbpm-spring-boot-sample-basic/src/main/resources/application-postgres.properties

then I tryed to start the application, but I got this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in org.jbpm.springboot.datasources.JBPMDataSourceAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.jdbc.XADataSourceWrapper' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.jdbc.XADataSourceWrapper' in your configuration.
```

The *JBPMDataSourceAutoConfiguration* class is linked below

https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/master/kie-spring-boot/kie-spring-boot-autoconfiguration/jbpm-spring-boot-data-sources/src/main/java/org/jbpm/springboot/datasources/JBPMDataSourceAutoConfiguration.java

How can I correctly configure an embedded integration of jbpm/drools/kie in my existing spring boot project?

----------UPDATE-------------

After setting the property `spring.jta.enabled = true`, the exception changed in

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in org.jbpm.springboot.datasources.JBPMDataSourceAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.jdbc.XADataSourceWrapper' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'xaDataSourceWrapper' in 'NarayanaConfiguration.GenericJdbcConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (narayana.dbcp.enabled=false) found different value in property 'narayana.dbcp.enabled'
    - Bean method 'xaDataSourceWrapper' in 'NarayanaConfiguration.GenericJdbcConfiguration' not loaded because Ancestor me.snowdrop.boot.narayana.autoconfigure.NarayanaConfiguration did not match
    - Bean method 'xaDataSourceWrapper' in 'NarayanaConfiguration.PooledJdbcConfiguration' not loaded because Ancestor me.snowdrop.boot.narayana.autoconfigure.NarayanaConfiguration did not match
    - Bean method 'xaDataSourceWrapper' in 'AtomikosJtaConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager'
    - Bean method 'xaDataSourceWrapper' in 'BitronixJtaConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'bitronix.tm.jndi.BitronixContext'


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.jdbc.XADataSourceWrapper' in your configuration.
```

Comment: What DB are you using? The error could trigger if the DB does not support XA. Can you also post the configuration you are using for the DB connection?

Comment: I'm using Postgres and this is the configuration in application.yml

```spring:
  datasource:
    url:      jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname
    username: user
    password: password
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource```

Comment: Which transaction manager are you using? As you need one for XA transactions

Comment: ```spring.jta.narayana.transaction-manager-id=1```

Comment: @chrisblo Did you have any luck solving this? I have two projects, one of which fails to start due to this and another runs ok.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral The problem was caused by the SpringBatchConfig class using in the same project with "@EnableBatchProcessing" annotation. It seems that those configurations goes in conflict with kie-server ones. I've removed that annotation and I've implemented manually the beans jobLauncher, jobRepository, jobExplorer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot uses an embedded tomcat.
It took me a lot of time to make jbpm engine work as a spring boot application with an embedded tomcat, a lot of configs and hacks, especially for the controller 's password which can't be loaded from JKS

So, you need to declare JNDI lookup resources manually.

```
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.ContextResource;
import org.kie.server.services.api.KieServer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@SpringBootApplication
public class KieServerApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KieServerApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        log.info("Starting  things");
        SpringApplication.run(KieServerApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Autowired
    private Environment env;


    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {



        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {



            @Override
            protected TomcatWebServer getTomcatWebServer(
                    Tomcat tomcat) {
                tomcat.enableNaming();
                return super.getTomcatWebServer(tomcat);
            }

            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {

                final ContextResource jbpmProjectDs = new ContextResource();
                jbpmProjectDs.setName("jdbc/jbpmProjectDs");
                jbpmProjectDs.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
                jbpmProjectDs.setProperty("driverClassName", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                jbpmProjectDs.setProperty("url",env.getProperty("spring.mamodb.datasource.url"));
                marjoryDs.setProperty("username", env.getProperty("spring.mamodb.datasource.username"));
                jbpmProjectDs.setProperty("password", env.getProperty("spring.mamodb.datasource.password"));
                context.getNamingResources().addResource(jbpmProjectDs);

                final ContextResource narayanaTransactionManager = new ContextResource();
                narayanaTransactionManager.setName("TransactionManager");
                narayanaTransactionManager.setType(javax.transaction.TransactionManager.class.getName());
                narayanaTransactionManager.setProperty("factory","org.jboss.narayana.tomcat.jta.TransactionManagerFactory");
                context.getNamingResources().addResource(narayanaTransactionManager);

                final ContextResource transactionSynchronizationRegistry = new ContextResource();
                transactionSynchronizationRegistry.setName("TransactionSynchronizationRegistry");
                transactionSynchronizationRegistry.setType(javax.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry.class.getName());
                transactionSynchronizationRegistry.setProperty("factory","org.jboss.narayana.tomcat.jta.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryFactory");
                context.getNamingResources().addResource(transactionSynchronizationRegistry);


            }
        };
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    public DataSource jndiDataSource() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        bean.setJndiName("java:comp/env/jdbc/jbpmProjectDs");
        bean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
        bean.setLookupOnStartup(false);
        bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return (DataSource) bean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner deployAndValidate() {

        return new CommandLineRunner() {
            @Autowired
            private KieServer kieServer;

            @Override
            public void run(String... strings) {
                log.info("KieServer {} started", kieServer);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

** properties Config **

```
#transaction manager configuration
spring.jta.narayana.transaction-manager-id="1"
narayana.transaction-manager-id=1
narayana.dbcp.enabled=true
narayana.dbcp.maxTotal=20
spring.jta.log-dir=./target/tx-object-store
narayana.periodic-recovery-period=10
narayana.recovery-backoff-period=10
```

POM file just for **dependencies:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-spring-boot-samples</artifactId>
    <version>7.29.0.Final</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>kie-server</artifactId>

  <name>KIE Server</name>
  <description>KIE Server SpringBoot </description>

  <properties>
        <version.org.keycloak>5.0.0</version.org.keycloak>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
      <artifactId>kie-server-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
      <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
          <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <!-- test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
          <artifactId>accessors-smart</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
          <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.kie.server</groupId>
      <artifactId>kie-server-client</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.narayana.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-jta</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-transaction-spi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>pull-parser</groupId>
      <artifactId>pull-parser</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
      <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
      <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.relaxng</groupId>
      <artifactId>relaxngDatatype</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
      <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
        <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.10</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.narayana.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jta</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.keycloak}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.17</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.marjory</groupId>
        <artifactId>model</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.99-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.marjory</groupId>
        <artifactId>marjory-jta</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.apache.cxf}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.23</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-spi</artifactId>
        <version>7.6.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>pull-parser</groupId>
        <artifactId>pull-parser</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.10</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
        <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.17</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.relaxng</groupId>
        <artifactId>relaxngDatatype</artifactId>
        <version>2011.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>mysql</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>QuickBuild</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
              <includes>
                <include>com/marjory/kie/server/*.java</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>go-to-hell</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

  </profiles>
</project>
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

just go to start.jbpm.org and
download ready made spring booy kie-server!

Comment: This does not remotely answer the question.