# How to create a Batch project that doesn't need a data source?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am creating a batch project that does not have a need to hit a database and when I run a context load, I get an exception

> "Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException:
> Failed to determine a suitable driver class".

I believe that there are a few dependencies like spring-data-jpa, that may require a data source to be supplied within my project and when I add a random data source, my context loads just fine.

Comment: Why would you use Spring Data JPA if you don't have a database? If you don't have a database then don't provide dependencies that require one (like jdbc, spa etc.).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot + spring batch without DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913918/spring-boot-spring-batch-without-datasource)